# How to connect the ssh server using the ssh passphrase using shell script

Tags: shell, ssh, ssh-keys, passphrase

We are writing the automatic script to connect my servers using the shell script. We do not have the password for the server. We have only public ssh passphrase. We have tried passphrase instead of the password in this comment but it says permission denied `sshpass -p password ssh user@host`. Is there any way to connect the server through public passphrase in the shell script?

Comment: Does your question imply that you never managed to connect/authenticate to the server? If that's the case, you need to contact your server Administrator, not ask on a public forum.

Comment: No. We are connecting the our servers using this passphrase only. Now we are writing the automated script the connect the server and copy some of files via the script. Thats why are looking for the comment to login into the IP using ssh passphrase in scripts.

Comment: I assume you mean *"command"*, not *"comment"*, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a private key automatically, just remove the passphrase.

To remove a passphrase, you can use:

```
ssh-keygen -p -P passphrasse -N "" -f keyfile
```

---

*Though `sshpass` should work too, while it makes a little sense using it for this purpose.*